# UISegmented Control Exception Thrown

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, methods

when clicking the button action down below, I get an exception:

**-[UIRoundedRectButton selectedSegmentIndex]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8178b90** ;
'

(it is also initialized as - (IBAction)genderBtn:(id)sender;  in the header file).

I do not know if I should somehow initialize this into another method or not or initialized globally.  Any method ideas would be much appreciated.

```
- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender {

  double BAC=0;

  //  NSString *weight=weightTextField.text;

  //Other variables etc.

UISegmentedControl *gender = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;


   UIButton *gender = (UIButton *)sender;


if (gender.selected == 0 ) {



} else if (gender.selected = 1){



}


UIAlertView *alertMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Results:"
                                          message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Your Percentage is: "]
                                         delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alertMessage show];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that although you think the sender value is a UISegmentedControl, it isn't. It's a UIRoundedRectButton. The result is that you end up sending a message to which only a UISegmentedControl implements to the UIRoundedRectButton, thus it does not recognize the selector. Make sure this action is connected to the right type of button.

---

EDIT: Alright. I looked at your code from before. I thought the problem was that you used a normal UIButton instead of a UISegmentedControl, but the problem seems to really be that you shouldn't be using the sender argument *at all*.

I take it that you have one UISegmentedControl for the user to select something, and one UIButton for them to tap when they're done with their selection. The problem was that you were asking the sender argument (which was the submit button) what the selection state of the UISegmentedControl was. You need to store the UISegmentedControl in a property and use that in your submit method to get the selectedSegmentIndex.

```
- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender {

    double BAC=0;

    //NSString *weight=weightTextField.text;

    //Other variables etc.

    UISegmentedControl *gender = self.segmentedControl;


    if (gender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ) {
        //something
    } else if (gender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
        //something
    }

    UIAlertView *alertMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Results:"
                                          message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Your Percentage is: "]
                                         delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertMessage show];
}
```

The submit button calls this when it is pressed and gets the selected index from the segmented control which you store in a property.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl* segmentedControl; //goes in @interface

@synthesize segmentedControl = _segmentedControl; //goes in @implementation
```

Hook this IBOutlet to your segmented control and use that.

Comment: I am rather new to iOS, I want to use the UISegmentedControl in an if statement within the submitButton action.  Is this possible?  I set the action of the segmented control to the Sent Events in the view controller for the submit button and I still get the same error.

Comment: Yes, it is. The only problem here is that the `sender` argument in the method you posted is not a UISegementedControl: it's a UIButton. The action is set up to a button and the method *does* get called; it's just not hooked up to the correct TYPE of button. The result is that you try to get the `selectedSegementIndex` of the button of an incorrect type, so it throws an exception. I have no idea what you're talking about by "initializing" methods that have completely irrelevant signatures anyways. Maybe you wanted a property? I also don't know what the last sentence means in your comment.

Comment: The UIButton worked with fixing the crash, but now every-time I click either option out of the two, It shows my alertview before clicking the submitButton.  See above please.  I do not know what was wrong with my previous type of button.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I edited my answer. You had a segmented control with a button that should submit what's selected on the segmented control, right? If that's the case, then you don't want to use the sender argument; it's the submit button, which knows nothing of the segmented control. You need to store you segmented control in a property and query IT, not the sender.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'm coming from near zero experience of iOS so this has helped out immensely.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I misunderstood you at first! I suggest you read Apple's documentation on Objective-C, Xcode and Cocoa Touch, as well as get a good book. One good thing about Objective-C is that things usually have pretty self explanatory names. For instance, `sender` is whatever sent the message, such as the button you tapped on, or `colorWithRed:blue:green:alpha:`, which returns a color with the RGBA values you specify. :)